# how to remove gibberish that exhibits no pattern using python nltk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I am writing a code to clean the urls and extract just the underlying text.

```
 train_str = train_df.to_string()
 letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", train_str)
 words = letters_only.lower().split()
 stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))
 stops.update(['url','https','http','com'])
 meaningful_words = [w for w in words if not w in stops]
 long_words = [w for w in meaningful_words if len(w) > 3]
```

Using the above code i am able to extract just the words after removing the punctuations, stopwords, etc. But i am unable to remove the words that are gibberish in nature. These are some of the many words that i get after cleaning the urls.

```
['uact', 'ahukewim', 'asvpoahuhxbqkhdtibveqfggtmam', 'fchrisalbon','afqjcnhil', 'ukai', 'khnaantjejdfrhpeza']
```

There is no particular pattern in their occurrence or in the letters to use regex or other functions. Could anyone suggest any ways in which these words could be removed?
Thanks!

Comment: how are the words structured. a list of strings like in your example?

Comment: @MattR these are some of the words ['instant', 'espv', 'string', 'pandas', 'dataframe'] , ['dataframe', 'importing', 'html', 'afqjcnhil', 'ukai', 'khnaantjejdfrhpeza']. Sorry i don't get what you mean by how the words are structured?

Comment: The words you are trying to clean. it looks like they are a list of strings? You are trying to loop through them and remove "junk words" from this list, yes? PS: I Know i can solve this.. I have to download the entire NLTK package. In the meantime please download the entire nltk package as well if you have not already `import nltk` `nltk.download()`

Comment: @MattR Yes you are right. They are list of strings and i am looking to clean the junk words. Yeah i already have the nltk package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an empty list. Loop through all the words in the current list. use `words.words()` from the corpera to check if it is a real world. Append all the "non-junk words" to that new list. Use that new list for whatever you'd like.

```
from nltk.corpus import words

test = ['uact', 'ahukewim', 'asvpoahuhxbqkhdtibveqfggtmam', 'fchrisalbon',\
'afqjcnhil', 'ukai', 'khnaantjejdfrhpeza', 'this', 'is' , 'a' , 'word']
final = []

for x in test:
    if x in words.words():
        final.append(x)
print(final)
```

output:

```
['this', 'is', 'a', 'word']
```

Comment: @Josephine. No Problem. NLTK is an extensive package. See the documentation [http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html]. I searched under Section 4.1

Comment: The problem with this is that even relatively trivial texts can contain legitimate non-dictionary words. People coin new words all the time. Just because you haven't seen, say, *fantabulosity* before doesn't necessarily mean it's gibberish (depending of course also on your definition of "gibberish").

Comment: If all their words are "made up" I'd say that the sentence is gibberish. Like who does that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('words')

words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())

sent = "basldlad and Rakadajlnv  share"

" ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sent) \

         if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())
```

1.) The 'nltk.download('words')' downloads a corpus of english words.

2.) The 'set(nltk.corpus.words.words())' creates a set of english
words and assigns it to words.

3.) The final loop just extracts each word from your sentence and
checks whether it is part of the words corpus and also is not an
alphanumeric.

4.) Please note proper nouns like names of persons will also be
treated here as gibberish.

5.) For handling proper nouns you need to do named-entity recognition